# Is there a plotting library which allows me to drill down and roll up on a social network type graph

Tags: plot, graph, analytics, sna

I want to plot a social network for linkage analysis. Very specifically, I have a dataset with call data showing who interacted whom at what time.

In the resulting interactive graph, I should be able to (preferably) click on one node to look into it's neighbors only (all other nodes and edges get hidden). I should be able to do this recursively. This is equivalent to a drill-down procedure. I should then be able to roll-up to reveal the parent view to my current view.

As an example, consider the following network
[Full Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw2Y2.png)

Lets say I clicked on "C". The result should be
[Network for C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4GxC.png)

Now, I can click on "I" to view only its network and so forth. At all stages, it is possible to return to the view that came before current view.

What are the recommended plotting libraries for recreation of this requirement? The most popular libraries in Python and R don't have this particular feature, as far as I could see.

Comment: Note requesting library recommendations is offtopic for the site.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Please point me to the right Stack Exchange site to post this on. Thanks

Comment: There's a Software Recommendation site where this *may* be ontopic. I don't use it though, so I can't be sure. Read their site tour first to be sure.